# Random string from an array whose index is a string

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pick an item from an array but randomly. The problem is that the indexes of the array are string. How can I select an item from this array but with a random index.

Nb: Indexes are string,  I found answers with integer indexes but not string.

```
//................................................
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigBlue: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});

//.......................................................

return (
  //if index was integer
  <Text style={styles[Math.floor(Math.random()*styles.length)]}>{this.props.text}</Text>
  // I need something like this : styles[RandomStringIndex()]
);
```

Comment: Please include code showing what you currently have

Comment: `lenght` well that would be one problem

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want either `Object.keys` or `Object.values`.

Both of these convert an object's key:value mapping into a numbered array.

**The Object.keys way:**

```
var array_of_keys = Object.keys(styles);
var random_key = array_of_keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_of_keys.length)];
var random_value = styles[random_key];
```

**The Object.values way:**

```
var array_of_values = Object.values(styles);
var random_value = array_of_values[Math.floor(Math.random()*array_of_values.length)];
```